# Getting Borel-measurability from a product measure space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures, product-measure

I have that the graph of a function $G(f) = \{ (x, f(x)) : x \in \mathbb{R} \} $ for $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R} $ is such that $G(f) ∈ B \otimes B$. Here $B$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets.  How can I go about showing that $f$ is Borel-measurable? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $g(x)=(x,f(x))$ is measurable. Consider $g^{-1}(G(f) \cap [\mathbb R \times (-\infty, a)]$

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. You've stumped me though, can you elaborate?